# is it possible to using mirror address in the docker build stage

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker

I want to build the bitnami postgresql container by myself(I want to add some custom feature, I want to add the zhparser plugin into postgresql container), the problem I am facing is that download package from official address is so low(I have been waiting for hours), seems impossible to complete the build if using official address to fetch the package, is it possible to using the mirror address in the docker build stage? so that I could download from mirror address to speed up the build process. This is the Dockefile:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:bullseye
ENV HOME="/" \
    OS_ARCH="amd64" \
    OS_FLAVOUR="debian-11" \
    OS_NAME="linux"

ARG EXTRA_LOCALES=""
ARG WITH_ALL_LOCALES="no"

COPY prebuildfs /
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
# Install required system packages and dependencies
RUN install_packages acl ca-certificates curl gzip libbsd0 libbz2-1.0 libc6 libedit2 libffi7 libgcc-s1 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libhogweed6 libicu67 libidn2-0 libldap-2.4-2 liblz4-1 liblzma5 libmd0 libncurses6 libnettle8 libp11-kit0 libpcre3 libreadline8 libsasl2-2 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstdc++6 libtasn1-6 libtinfo6 libunistring2 libuuid1 libxml2 libxslt1.1 libzstd1 locales procps tar zlib1g
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "gosu" "1.14.0-152" --checksum 0c751c7e2ec0bc900a19dbec0306d6294fe744ddfb0fa64197ba1a36040092f0
RUN . /opt/bitnami/scripts/libcomponent.sh && component_unpack "postgresql" "13.7.0-155" --checksum 0aeb44b6993a10dd3915599405c871d438509ffbb818ff548b644c627b9dd1c0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives
RUN chmod g+rwX /opt/bitnami
RUN localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure locales
RUN echo 'en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
RUN echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

COPY rootfs /
RUN /opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql/postunpack.sh
RUN /opt/bitnami/scripts/locales/add-extra-locales.sh
ENV APP_VERSION="13.7.0" \
    BITNAMI_APP_NAME="postgresql" \
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8" \
    LANGUAGE="en_US:en" \
    NSS_WRAPPER_LIB="/opt/bitnami/common/lib/libnss_wrapper.so" \
    PATH="/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin:$PATH"

VOLUME [ "/bitnami/postgresql", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d", "/docker-entrypoint-preinitdb.d" ]

EXPOSE 5432

USER 1001
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/postgresql/run.sh" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it is possible to using the mirror address, just add sources.list and put this content(replace the mirror address with differenet location):

```
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security buster/updates main
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-backports main non-free contrib
deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ buster-backports main non-free contrib
```

then add the sources.list like this:

```
FROM docker.io/bitnami/minideb:bullseye

ADD sources.list /etc/apt/
```